# Apache mod_rewrite rule to pass specific REQUEST_URI to specific html files

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a very basic html presentation which I want to use Apache mod_rewrite to handle the URLs.

`home.html` is just an intro page but I want this to be called when there is no `REQUEST_URI`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ home.html
```

`slides.html` renders all slides. I'm using handlebars.js to pull in data from a .json file and then render each slide according to the URL structure below: `/?q=N`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\?q=\d+$
RewriteRule ^ slides.html
```

Both seems to work fine but not when both are present. What am I missing?

Comment: share some logs please

Answer (score 0):

Your first rewrite rule doesn't need a `RewriteCond` and the two rules need to be ordered correctly.

Your second rule (to do with slides.html) is working by accident. The query string is not part of `%{REQUEST_URI}`. You need something like the following (untested):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=\d+$
RewriteRule ^/$ slides.html [L]

RewriteRule ^/$ home.html [L]
```

I've added [L] flags to prevent further rewriting, but you can remove then if you need to do more to the URI path.